# How to debug CI/CD script in github forked repo?

Tags: cmake, continuous-integration, github-actions, pull-request

There is a public repo on GitHub with CI/CD workflow and bash scripts. I created a fork of it and then create a PR to that repo.

But my PR failed during the merge CI/CD. By some initial investigation I think it's not my changed code but the CI/CD script issue.

So I want to debug (or change and test) the CI/CD scripts, but I don't know to to do it.

In my own fork, I can enabled github Actions, but I don't see any workflow that I can run by myself. (https://github.com/felixf4xu/Lanelet2/actions)

Should I go to the original repo and keep pushing new commits to trigger the CI/CD test?

or should I setup new workflows in my own fork so that I can manually trigger the script?

or test the scripts locally with docker setup?

Thanks.

Comment: So you cannot trigger a re-run from https://github.com/felixf4xu/Lanelet2/actions/runs/6243344078? I don't think so.